# Simple select query in python fails

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

my problem is I want to perform a select query in python but it fails.

```
def check_account(cur, account_id):
    sql = """SELECT description FROM accounts WHERE id = %s;"""
    acc_desc = None
    try:
        cur.execute(sql, (account_id,))
        acc_desc = cur.fetchone()[0]
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)

    return acc_desc
```

This solution doesn't seem to work as it returns a None type, which is weird because when I execute this in my SQL console it returns what I want (text). The database connection is working as well because insert queries (which are coded similarly to this) work as they should. I'm using postgresql and python 3.8.5 as well as the psycopg2 library for database connection and cursor.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a valid account_id?

Comment: Yes, when I debug I check the cur.query attribute which shows a valid account_id which is present in my database. To add, I tried a simple "SELECT * FROM accounts" which returned NoneType as well.

Comment: What if you do this. `acc_desc = cur.fetchone()` without getting 1st index.

Comment: It still returns a NoneType, even when I try `cur.fetchall()` the result is an empty list.

Comment: What are you passing in as `account_id`, and what's the type of the `id` column?

Comment: `account_id` is of type `int` and `id` column in the table is of type `bigint`.

Comment: What is the output of `print(cur.mogrify(sql, (account_id,)))`?

Comment: It seems to be solved after I tried using a different library (asyncpg). Now even using psycopg2 I can retrieve data from the databse.